# Display an object property of local storage in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-options

In my Angular app, I store **`victim`** data in the local storage. In my view, **`victim`** data is displayed and we can update it (from `<select>`):

```
<h1>Victim #{{victim.numero}}</h1>

<label>Victim status</label>
<select ng-model="victim.status" ng-options="s.libelle for s in status"></select>

<label>Victim situation</label>
<select ng-model="victim.situation" ng-options="s for s in situations"></select>
```

The problem is that the value stored in `victim.status` is not displayed by default **when refreshing the page** (it is not null). The curious point is that is works well for `victim.numero` and `victim.situation`.

---

With the following Fiddle, here is a scenario to see the bug:

1. Open the Fiddle
2. **status** input will be void, although the binded **variable is set**
3. Modify it, click "*Save changes*": it is displayed correctly
4. Press F5: The variable is correctly updated in local storage, but **still not displayed** in the input
5. Note that situation input still works correctly

The only difference between `victim.status` and `victim.situation` is that **status is an object** and **situation is a string**.

---

I've made a dummy code to reproduce the issue:

### [JSFiddle of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/f4oazj21/)

---

I want the status input to be default set with `victim.status` when loading the page, **how can I fix it**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your ng-options, as your select list is an object try adding  `track by`

```
 <select ng-model="victim.status" ng-options="s.libelle for s in status track by s.libelle"></select>
```

[JSFiddle of the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/f4oazj21/5/)

The reason you have to use track by is because your array in you select contains objects. This means the html that is produced ends up looking like this.

```
<select ng-model="victim.status" ng-options="s.libelle for s in status" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="Unknown" value="object:3">Unknown</option>
    <option label="Safe" value="object:4">Safe</option>
    <option label="Dead" value="object:5">Dead</option>
</select>
```

[image]

As you can see from this your value `victim.status` doesn't equal `object:4`.

What track by does is replaces the value in the value attribute and uses the property of the model instead of the whole model. So you're html comes out like this.

```
<select ng-model="victim.status" ng-options="s.libelle for s in status track by s.libelle" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <option label="Unknown" value="Unknown" selected="selected">Unknown</option>
    <option label="Safe" value="Safe">Safe</option>
    <option label="Dead" value="Dead">Dead</option>
</select>
```

And instead of doing does `victim.status === "Safe"` it will do `victim.status.libelle == "safe"`

I hope this explains it well enough, if you want any more clarification let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it fixed my issue!